# Is there an alternative to paired t-test two multilevel ordinal variables? (similar to McNemar test)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

Suppose I have two variables that measure some form of severity of illness on identical ordinal scale; one measured before treatment and the other measured after the treatment.

I want to test if there is an improvement between treatments.

Non-parametric correlations wouldn't be suitable; they would tell me if there is a relationship between the condition before and after the treatment.

Comment: Paired-sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test is the best choice. Or, less sensitive - sign test (which is equivalent to NcNemar's in case of dichotomous data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with ordinal logistic regression models and mixed-effects models with `lmer` in the `lme4` package, you may want to check out the `clmm` function in the `ordinal` package. This function, built on `lmer`, may prove especially useful if you have covariates to control for.

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

1. As ttnphns pointed out, the Wilcoxon sign-rank test is indeed the nonparametric analog to the paired *t* test (just as McNemar's test is the binary outcome analog to the paired *t* test).
2. You write that nonparametric correlations (presumably Spearman's $r_{\text{S}}$) "wouldn't be suitable; they would tell me if there is a relationship between the condition before and after the treatment."

   But I would suggest that $r_{\text{S}}$ tells you if there is an association between *group* and *severity of illness*, and further, that (assuming $d_{i}=\text{rank}_{\text{pre}}-\text{rank}_{\text{post}}$) the sign of $r_{\text{S}}$ tells you whether that association is a monotonic decrease ($r_{\text{S}} > 0$ implies that the post group had lower severity), or a monotonic increase ($r_{\text{S}} < 0$ implies that the post group had higher severity).